# How to extract json elements to variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have json string like this:

```
[
{"COMPLIANCE_ID":"1/FIRST/US/191CC2/20160906/pW1WSpD/1","TOLERANCE":null,"WEIGHTED_ARR_LAST_SLP":"0.03801186624130076","SLIPPAGE_INTERVAL_VWAP_BPS":"10.2711","ROOT_ORDER_ID":"735422197553491","ENTERING_TRADER":"duffy_dma2","SECURITY_ID":"EOG.N","ARRIVAL_MID_PX":"93.6100","WEIGHTED_ARR_SLP":"0.12323190317127024","AVG_PX":"93.6586","ORDER_CCY":"USD","LEAVES_QTY":"0","WEIGHT":"0.02372627566400397","INITIATING_TRADER":null,"PARTICIPATION_RATE":"0E-12","LOCAL_REF_END_TIME":"2016-09-06 06:00:27.775","WEIGHTED_IVWAP_SLP":"0.2436949499725512","NOTIONAL_USD":"477940","LIST_ID":null,"SYM":"EOG","LIQ_CONSUMPTION":"15.21","URGENCY":null,"SIDE":"Sell Short","ALGO":"Hydra","EXECUTING_TRADER":"duffy_dma2","EXEC_QTY":"5103","CL_ORD_ID":"7245294057012908344","LOCAL_REF_START_TIME":"2016-09-06 05:59:57.844","SLIPPAGE_END_LAST_ARR_LAST_BPS":"1.6021","ORD_STATUS":"Filled","IVWAP_PX":"93.5625","LIMIT_PX":"93.6100","ORDER_ID":"735422197553491","VOLUME_LIMIT":"0E-12","SLIPPAGE_ARR_MID_BPS":"5.1939","ORDER_QTY":"5103","CLIENT_ACRONYM":"PEAKM","EXECUTION_STYLE":"2"},{"COMPLIANCE_ID":"1/FIRST/US/191CC2/20160906/pW1PUxP/1","TOLERANCE":null,"WEIGHTED_ARR_LAST_SLP":"-0.046488357264395964","SLIPPAGE_INTERVAL_VWAP_BPS":"0.1625","ROOT_ORDER_ID":"73855219760798","ENTERING_TRADER":"duffy_dma2","SECURITY_ID":"MCD.N","ARRIVAL_MID_PX":"118.0950","WEIGHTED_ARR_SLP":"-0.0041198933937856425","AVG_PX":"118.0923","ORDER_CCY":"USD","LEAVES_QTY":"0","WEIGHT":"0.01830250285999841","INITIATING_TRADER":null,"PARTICIPATION_RATE":"0E-12","LOCAL_REF_END_TIME":"2016-09-06 05:32:24.895","WEIGHTED_IVWAP_SLP":"0.002974156714749742","NOTIONAL_USD":"368684","LIST_ID":null,"SYM":"MCD","LIQ_CONSUMPTION":"62.82","URGENCY":null,"SIDE":"Sell","ALGO":"Hydra","EXECUTING_TRADER":"duffy_dma2","EXEC_QTY":"3122","CL_ORD_ID":"7244573979975932119","LOCAL_REF_START_TIME":"2016-09-06 05:32:19.697","SLIPPAGE_END_LAST_ARR_LAST_BPS":"-2.5400","ORD_STATUS":"Filled","IVWAP_PX":"118.0904","LIMIT_PX":"117.9900","ORDER_ID":"73855219760798","VOLUME_LIMIT":"0E-12","SLIPPAGE_ARR_MID_BPS":"-0.2251","ORDER_QTY":"3122","CLIENT_ACRONYM":"PEAKM","EXECUTION_STYLE":"4"}]
```

which I'm getting from another file in a js file:

```
var jsondata = document.getElementById("jsonArray").value;
```

How do I extract json elements from jsondata to variables like this:

```
RefData.COMPLIANCE_ID = [
        "1/FIRST/US/191CC2/20160906/pW1WSpD/1", "1/FIRST/US/191CC2/20160906/pW1PUxP/1"
    ];
```

etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work.

```
var jsondata = document.getElementById("jsonArray").value;
var json = JSON.parse(jsondata);

json.map(function(obj) {
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  keys.forEach(function(key) {
    if (!RefData[key]) {
      RefData[key] = [];
    }
    RefData[key].push(obj[key]);
  });
});
```

At this point RefData should have properties like COMPLIANCE_ID, TOLERANCE, WEIGHTED_ARR_LAST_SLP... etc.  That are all arrays with 2 values.

Comment: RefData is the name of my js file (RefData.js) which has export default class RefData {}

var jsondata = document.getElementById("jsonArray").value;
var json = JSON.parse(jsondata);

Comment: And I want variables like RefData.COMPLIANCE_ID, RefData.TOLERANCE etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var json = JSON.parse(jsondata );

var compliance_id = json["COMPLIANCE_ID"];
```

Comment: I don't want to display any alert box, but just store it to a variable and use it further.

Comment: @Angad edited to save the value in a var.